# AE Extendscript remove marker by name

Tags: adobe, effects, extendscript

I'm working on an After Effects Script, which includes a visual GUI list of all markers on a layer. Marker names are used multiple times, so e.g. all markers on the layer could be "start, start, start, end". When selecting a marker name from the list, I want to remove the nearest marker of this kind (e.g. name="start") in my timeline.

(For a better idea of what I mean, here's a screeshot)[image]
Clicking on the minus button executes the function.

I successfully got the marker by name, but can't seem to delete the selected marker. My script is the following:

```
var removeMarker = function(layer, listbox) {

        var selected = listbox.selection, // returns the selected marker name
            t = layer.time;

    var marker = layer.property("Marker"),
        markerClosest = marker.keyValue(marker.nearestKeyIndex(t));


        if(selected != null && selected.toString()==markerClosest.comment) { // if name provided by selection equals selected
            marker.removeKey(markerClosest)
        }

}
```

According to [AE Scripting Guide](http://docs.aenhancers.com/property/?highlight=removekey#property-nearestkeyindex), nearestKeyIndex() should return an integer which I could use to delete the Marker via removeKey().
nearestKeyIndex() returns and object though.

Any ideas?
Thanks so much in advance!
Simon

Comment: Have you tried `nearestKeyIndex(t).value`? (just guessing)

Comment: Hey @stib, thanks for taking the time to answer.
Sadly, that didn't work. Actually, stringifying the return of nearestKeyIndex(t) returns {"chapter":"","comment":"start","cuePointName":"","duration":0.4,"eventCuePoint":true,"frameTarget":"","url":""}, so it kind of makes me wonder if the information I'm looking for is even stored in this command..

Comment: So it looks like it's returning the marker object, rather than its index. Have you tried `markerClosest.index`?

Comment: Yes I have. Sadly, the return is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The After Effects Markers property not giving a lot of information like other properties.

You need to iterate over the markers and for each of them you need to check if the time is after your current time, and the marker name (comment), and then remove this key by it's index:

```
function removeMarker(layer, listbox) {
    var markerName = listbox.selection.toString();
    var marker = layer.property('Marker');
    var t = layer.time;
    for (var i = 1; i <= marker.numKeys; i++) {
        if (marker.keyTime(i) >= t && marker.keyValue(i).comment === markerName) {
            marker.removeKey(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gosh, this is beautifully simple!
I've battled the marker property so long I overlooked the simplest solutions.
Thank you so much, Ziki!